# printing only the final iteration

Tags: python

i have written a code, it returns a list that is an update of a previous list.  i just need help figuring out how to return only the final value

```
def doit(company,action,currency_code,amount,bank):
    amount_in_usd = convert_to_usd(currency_code,amount)
    newlist=[]
    if action == "BUY":
        amount = float(amount) - amount_in_usd
        y=([company,amount])
        newlist.append(y)
        for index, values in enumerate(newlist):
            bank[values[0]]=(bank[values[0]]+values[1])
            if index == len(newlist) - 1:

                return bank
    if action == "SELL":
        amount = float(amount) + amount_in_usd
        y=([company,amount])
        newlist.append(y)
        for index, values in enumerate(newlist):
            bank[values[0]]=(bank[values[0]]+values[1])
            if index == len(newlist) - 1:

                return bank
```

i need bank to be returned only once

Comment: ... `return bank[-1]`?

Comment: Your last statement seems to conflict with what you said before the code. If you want to return the final value of the `bank` list, use @Kevin 's comment. If you want `bank` to be returned, use Emilio's answer. If you want something else, you'll need to add more clarification.

Comment: a complete [mcve] plus expected/actual output ought to clear up all this confusion.

Comment: i tried both and neither of them will work, it cant recognize [-1]

Comment: What do you mean by "cant recognize". Can you please be more specific. It really would be of great help if you can be more specific with these details. More importantly, to link what Kevin posted again: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read that and make the necessary changes to your post so we can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the output is a dictionary how would i get the final value of a dictionary?

Comment: You are going to need to use an `OrderedDict` if you want the last entry of a dictionary, or instead of that just `return bank, values[0]` and then you will have the key to that value

Comment: im still having problems returning only the last value

Answer (score 0):

Have a single `return bank` statement a the end of the function, not conditional to anything. Remove both such statements as they currently are.

Comment: it still prints them all